# Flutter Dart consumindo muita memória RAM durante o build

Tags: memória, flutter, dart, memory-limit

Tenho instalado o flutter para web, desktop e android. O problema acontece em todas as plataformas que tento rodar um projeto, e demora muito para construir o projeto, antes não demorava tanto assim e também não consumia toda minha memória ram. Existe alguma forma de limitar a memória do flutter? Ou será que isso seria um problema nessa versão do Flutter?
Tenho 8GB de RAM instalado e se deixo o dart construindo o projeto ele acaba consumindo tudo e o android studio para de responder.
[image: Gerenciador de Tarefas mostrando o consumo de ram durante o Build para Web(Chrome)]
[image: Flutter Doctor]

Comment: Está utilizando vscode? Quais extensões?

Comment: Estou utilizando o android studio apenas com os plugins básicos "Flutter" e "Dart".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deletei as pastas ".dart_tool", "build" e "test". Reiniciei o PC e agora durante o build o dart chega a usar no máximo 500-400MB.

[image: Print do gerenciador de tarefas durante o build do projeto depois de deletar as pastas e reiniciar o PC]